# Can a sewer vent pipe be rerouted?

Tags: vent, sewer

We are adding a new shower and want to extend it by a few inches. But behind it is a sewer vent that has a bump out framed around it. It is on exterior wall and the roof is directly above it.

Can it be moved or rerouted so it is not in the way of the shower?

Also, strangely there is no bathroom directly below it. Just a bedroom. What is it actually venting?

Thanks.

[image]
Picture of vent pipe.

Comment: Is there a horizontal line that connects to that vent stack, say from kitchen or laundry fixtures on the floor below?

Comment: It probably vents the toilet and/or shower drain.

Comment: 1)  Is that cast iron?  2) Where would you reroute it to?

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a vent (a dry vent) then yes you can re-route it using 89 degree or 45 degree bends etc. the vent pipe must fall (slope) towards the sewer along its entire length.